# Need help adding data from database into a reacttable using react.js

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to React.js and i want to create an app that uses Microsoft SQL SERVER MANAGER +.net+ React for client side.I want to have a search filter in the react table so I can search each column from the table which is filled with data from MSSM.The app is working if i don t use a search engine but I really need to for my project.The problem is from the client side in Car.js  I guess.Thanks in advice!
I'll put the code components  and the error below

EDIT 
i want to replace "data[]"(which is hardcorded) from the following link ,with my "cars" taken from the database

link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-visvesvaraya-347r5?file=/src/styles.css:0-58

**Car.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from'react-bootstrap';
import {Button,ButtonToolbar} from'react-bootstrap';
import {AddCarModal} from'./AddCarModal';
import {EditCarModal} from './EditCarModal';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import GlobalSearchComponent from "./GlobalSearchComponent";
import "react-table-v6/react-table.css";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactTable from "react-table";







export class Car extends Component
{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={cars:[] ,addModalShow : false, editModalShow :false, filteredData: [],
        columns: [],
        searchInput: ""}
   }
   componentDidMount()
   {
       this.refreshList();

       this.getColumns();

   }
   refreshList()
   {

    fetch('https://localhost:44385/api/car')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data=> {
           this.setState({cars:data});
       }
       );
    }
        componentDidUpdate(){
            this.refreshList();
        }

   deleteCar( carid)
   {
     if(window.confirm('Are you sure?'))
     {
         fetch('https://localhost:44385/api/car/' + carid,{
          method:'DELETE',
          headers :{'Accept' :'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json' 
          }
         })
     }
    }




      getColumns = () => {
        let columns = [
          {
            Header: "Model Name",
            accessor: "modelName",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Model Name"
          },
          {
            Header: "Fuel Type",
            accessor: "fueltype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Fuel type "
          },
          {
            Header: "Body Type",
            accessor: "bodytype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Body Type "
          },
          {
            Header: "Price interval",
            accessor: "priceinterval",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Visits "
          },
          {
            Header: "Offroad rank",
            accessor: "offroadrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Offroad rank "
          },
          {
            Header: "Maximum speed interval",
            accessor: "maximumspeedinterval",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Maximum speed interval"
          },
          {
            Header: "Luxury rank",
            accessor: "luxuryrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Luxury rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Reliability rank",
            accessor: "reliabilityrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Reliability rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Safety rank",
            accessor: "safetyrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Safety rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Practicality rank",
            accessor: "practicalityrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Practicality rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Drive rank",
            accessor: "driverank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Drive rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Interior rank",
            accessor: "interiorrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Interior rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Good for city traffic?",
            accessor: "forcity",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Yes or No? "
          },
          {
            Header: "Good for long distance?",
            accessor: "forlong",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Yes or No? "
          },
          {
            Header: "Consumption",
            accessor: "consumption",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Consumption"
          },
          {
            Header: "Electric consumption",
            accessor: "econsumption",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Electric consumption"
          },
          {
            Header: "Engine type",
            accessor: "enginetype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Engine type"
          },
          {
            Header: "Cylinder number",
            accessor: "cylidnernumber",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Cylinder number"
          },
          {
            Header: "Naturally Aspired or Turbo?",
            accessor: "naot",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Naturally Aspired or Turbo?"
          },
          {
            Header: "Number of seats",
            accessor: "seatsnumber",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Number of seats"
          },
          {
            Header: "Cargo space",
            accessor: "cargo",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Cargo space "
          },
          {
            Header: "Options",
            accessor: "option",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Option "
          }
        ];
        this.setState({ columns });
      };



      handleSetData = cars => {
        console.log(cars);
        this.setState({ cars });
      };



      handleSetFilteredData = filteredData => {
        this.setState({ filteredData });
      };

      handleSetSearchInput = searchInput => {
        this.setState({ searchInput });
      };
    render() {

      let{cars,carid,carname,carfuel,carbody,carprice,caroffroad,carspeed,carluxury,carreliability,carsafety,carpracticality,cardrive,carinterior,carcity,cardistance,
        carconsumption,careconsumption,carengine,carcylinder,carnaot,carseats,carcargo ,filteredData, columns, searchInput }=this.state;

      const dataToDisplay = searchInput.length ? filteredData : cars;

    let addModalClose=()=> this.setState({addModalShow:false});
        let editModalClose=()=> this.setState({editModalShow:false});
        return(
       <div>
   <GlobalSearchComponent
          cars={this.state.cars}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          handleSetFilteredData={this.handleSetFilteredData}
          handleSetSearchInput={this.handleSetSearchInput}
        />

<Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
<thead>
 <tr>

 <ReactTable
          cars={dataToDisplay}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />

 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{cars.map(cr=>
    <tr key ={cr.id}> 

    <td> {cr.modelName }  </td>
    <td> {cr.fueltype }  </td>
    <td> {cr.bodytype}  </td>
    <td> {cr.priceinterval }  </td>
    <td> {cr.offroadrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.maximumspeedinterval }  </td>
    <td> {cr.luxuryrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.reliabilityrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.safetyrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.practicalityrank}  </td>
    <td> {cr.driverank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.interiorrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.forcity }  </td>
    <td> {cr.forlong }  </td>
    <td> {cr.consumption }  </td>
    <td> {cr.electricconsumption}  </td>
    <td> {cr.enginetype }  </td>
    <td> {cr.cylindernumber }  </td>
    <td> {cr.naot }  </td>
    <td> {cr.seatsnumber }  </td>
    <td> {cr.cargo }  </td>
    <td>
        <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button 
                   className="mr-2" variant ="info"
                    onClick={()=> this.setState({editModalShow : true , 
                        carid:cr.id, carname:cr.modelName, 
                    carfuel:cr.fueltype,carbody:cr.bodytype,
            carprice:cr.priceinterval,caroffroad:cr.offroadrank,
            carspeed:cr.maximumspeedinterval,  carluxury:cr.luxuryrank,
            carreliability:cr.reliabilityrank,carsafety:cr.safetyrank,
            carpracticality:cr.practicalityrank,cardrive:cr.driverank,
            carinterior:cr.interiorrank,carcity:cr.forcity,
            cardistance:cr.forlong,carconsumption:cr.consumption,
            careconsumption:cr.electricconsumption,carengine:cr.enginetype,
            carcylinder:cr.cylindernumber,carnaot:cr.naot,
            carseats:cr.seatsnumber,carcargo:cr.cargo})}
           >
               Edit 
           </Button>

          <Button className="mr-2"
          onClick={()=> this.deleteCar(cr.id)} 
          variant="danger"
          > Delete</Button>

                <EditCarModal
                       show = {this.state.editModalShow}
                       onHide={editModalClose}
                       carid={carid}
                       carname={carname}
                       carfuel={carfuel}
                       carbody={carbody}
                        carprice={carprice}
                       caroffroad={caroffroad}
                       carspeed={carspeed}
                       carluxury={carluxury}
                       carreliability={carreliability}
                        carsafety={carsafety}
                       carpracticality={carpracticality}
                       cardrive={cardrive}
                       carinterior={carinterior}
                       carcity={carcity}
                       cardistance={cardistance}
                       carconsumption={carconsumption}
                       careconsumption={careconsumption}
                        carengine={carengine}
                        carcylinder={carcylinder}
                        carnaot={carnaot}
                        carseats={carseats}
                         carcargo={carcargo}
              />
             </ButtonToolbar>
         </td>
    </tr>
)}
        </tbody>
 </Table>


 <ButtonToolbar>
     <Button
     variant='primary'
     onClick={()=> this.setState({addModalShow: true})}
     >Add Car </Button>

     <AddCarModal
         show={this.state.addModalShow}
         onHide={addModalClose}
     />
 </ButtonToolbar>







 </div>

    )

    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Car />, rootElement);
```

**GlobalSearchComponent**

```
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

export default class GlobalSearchComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredData: [],
      columnSearch: "",
      searchInput: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchInput: val }, () => this.globalSearch());
    this.props.handleSetSearchInput(val);
  };

  globalSearch = () => {
    const { searchInput, columnSearch } = this.state;
    let filteredData = this.props.cars.filter(value => {
      if (columnSearch) {
        return value[columnSearch]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
      }
      return (
        value.modelName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.fueltype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.bodytype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.priceinterval.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.offroadrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.maximumspeedinterval.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.luxuryrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.reliabilityrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.safetyrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.practicalityrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.driverank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.interiorrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.forcity.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.forlong.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.consumption.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.econsumption.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.enginetype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.cylindernumber.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.naot.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.seatsnumber.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.cargo.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) 


          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
      );
    });

    this.props.handleSetFilteredData(filteredData);
  };

  setColumnSearch = e => {
    this.setState({ columnSearch: e.target.value }, () => this.globalSearch());
  };

  render() {
    const { columns } = this.props;
    const { columnSearch } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <br />
        <Input
          size="large"
          name="searchInput"
          value={this.state.searchInput || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          label="Search"
        />
        <select
          onChange={e => {
            e.persist();
            this.setColumnSearch(e);
          }}
          value={columnSearch}
        >
          <option value=""> All columns</option>
          {columns.map(col => {
            return <option value={col.accessor}>{col.Header}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Car`.
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/components/Car.js
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/src/components/Car.js:384
  381 |     }
  382 | }
  383 | const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
> 384 | ReactDOM.render(<Car />, rootElement);
  385 | 
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/App.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:129:73
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2613:62
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2758:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/Felix/source/repos/React/car-app/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:67
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using react table `version "^7.1.0"`. You can try this.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {useTable} from 'react-table'
import namor from 'namor';

const range = len => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr.push(i)
    }
    return arr
};

const newPerson = () => {
    const statusChance = Math.random();
    const jIncome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    const bIncome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    return {
        firstName: namor.generate({words: 1, numbers: 0}),
        lastName: namor.generate({words: 1, numbers: 0}),
        jIncome: jIncome,
        bIncome: bIncome,
        tIncome: jIncome + bIncome,
        progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        status:
            statusChance > 0.66
                ? 'relationship'
                : statusChance > 0.33
                ? 'complicated'
                : 'single',
    }
};

function makeData(...lens) {
    const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
        const len = lens[depth];
        return range(len).map(d => {
            return {
                ...newPerson(),
                subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
            }
        })
    };

    return makeDataLevel()
}

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Table({columns, data}) {
    // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    });

    // Render the UI for your table
    return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps(
                        {
                            style: {backgroundColor: row.values.tIncome > 50? 'skyblue': 'lightgray'}
                        }
                    )}>
                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                )
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}

function ReactTableRowColor() {
    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'Name',
                columns: [
                    {
                        Header: 'First Name',
                        accessor: 'firstName',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Last Name',
                        accessor: 'lastName',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                Header: 'Info',
                columns: [
                    {
                        Header: 'Job Income',
                        accessor: 'jIncome',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Business Income',
                        accessor: 'bIncome',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Total Income',
                        accessor: 'tIncome',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Status',
                        accessor: 'status',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Profile Progress',
                        accessor: 'progress',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        []
    );

    const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), []);

    return (
        <Styles>
            <Table columns={columns} data={data}/>
        </Styles>
    )
}

export default ReactTableRowColor
```

Comment: Hi,i would like to be like this https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-visvesvaraya-347r5?file=/src/styles.css:0-58